# Proving a recursive algorithm as correct using induction

Tags: algorithms, induction, recursion

My objective is to give a recursive algorithm for finding the maximum of a finite set of integers, "making use of the fact that the maximum of n integers is the larger of the last integer in the list and the maximum of the first n-1 integers in the list".

```
procedure maximum(L, i, j)
     if (i != j) return maximum(L, i+1, j)
     else if (i = j) return L[j]
     else return 0
end if
```

This is what I came up with, and now I'm supposed to prove it correct using induction.

As a basis step, I claimed that a list L containing the integer 1 with leftbound interval i = 1 and rightbound interval j = 1 would lead us to the second if statement and successfully returns 1.

In the inductive step I said that the inductive hypothesis is the statement that maximum(L, i, j) returns k whenever k is the maximum element in the list.

So I decided that I must show that maximum(L, i, j) returns L[j] = k+1 when $k+1$ is the maximum element in the list,
or in other words, the element located at the ``furthest right'' since the list is sorted.

Because k+1 is not anywhere before the end of the list, the algorithm will continuously take the path of the first if-statement
until i = j, when it will return L[j]. Since k+1 is the largest element in the sorted list and $j$ is the last index in the list, the 
algorithm returns the correct value.

Would this be a valid manner of proving a recursive algorithm as correct through the use of induction?

Comment: Your algorithm can never return anything but the $j$-th element of the list, for whatever $j$ you input initially.